# How do you output a frequency/note with a 1V octave keyboard controller?

Tags: frequency, oscillator, keyboard, synthesizer

To be specific, I made this:

[image]

[from here](http://www.musicfromouterspace.com/index.php?MAINTAB=SYNTHDIY&PROJARG=SINGLEBUSSKEYBOARD2007/SINGLEBUSSKEYBOARD2007.php&VPW=1917&VPH=830)

And to test the CV output, I used this schematic:

[image]

[from here](http://ecelab.com/circuit-vco-555.htm)

It works as a oscillator. Every time I hit a key it will oscillate at that note, but it wont stop.

How can I make it so that when I hit a key, it produces that note, and stops when the key is released?  (The circuit does not have to use a 555 timer, that is just what I have available at the moment.)

Comment: Please bring all relevant info to your question. We shouldn't have to click on links to figure out what you are doing.

Answer (score 1):

What does the CV output do at key-up when measured with a meter?

It should go to zero or negative depending on the opamp supplies.

Are you using the -12V as shown or ANY voltage there. That is the "stop" circuitry.

If you short the 555's pin 5 to ground that is the best stopped sttae you can expect unless you use a -12V supply as they suggest.

You need to provide SOME way to stop the 555 on key up.

Comment: Hey, a *short* answer from Russell! :-)